# Prevent perforce from demanding eclipse project files be checked out

Tags: eclipse, perforce

I'm currently working on several eclipse projects, using Perforce as my source control. I have the perforce eclipse plugin installed.

My problem is that eclipse likes to, for no particularly good reason, write to my .project or .classpath files. It also loves to change the order in which things appear. As such, it demands that I have these files checked out almost all the time. I've somewhat worked around this by creating a pending changelist called "Files which I've checked out for convenience" and stuffing all of the metadata objects that eclipse asks about there.

This has the downside that if anyone updates some metadata (for example, adding a new project reference or changing the classpaths) I now have to resolve differences before they'll show up, adding extra time and trouble to my project.

Coming from Subversion, this is a really rude surprise. With SVN I could just wait until I checked in and move these files to the ignore-on-commit changelist, as needed. SVN would also merge new updates into these files without bugging me.

Basically, is there any way to prevent eclipse from constantly futzing with my projects, or am I just stuck here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the .classpath and .project files are in version control, since that what causes them to be read only. There is an option in Perforce using P4V to make just those files always writable. Right click the files and select 'Change Filetype...' and select the +w Always writable in workspace option. This will affect all clients using that branch / stream, but now changes can be made without marking for edit first.

If you would like that to be the default for all of your depots, then you can have a Perforce admin to change the p4 typemap so that any new .classpath and .project files will be writable.

See http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/o.ftypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a .p4ignore file to the project root dir, containing

.classpath

.project

[Support docs for P4IGNORE](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/env.P4IGNORE.html)

Comment: Could you reference supporting documentation?